# Как вставить сообщение после удачного выполнения действия на laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

не давно начал изучать laravel и возник вопрос, как после вызова метода в контроллере вернуть какое ни будь сообщение? в CodeIgniter делал так:

```html
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-left">' . $this->lang->line('success_message') . '</div>');
   $this->load->view('test', $data);
```

Comment: [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data)

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и проверенный вариант

**Для сообщения об успехе операции:**

В контроллере

```
return redirect()->route('ваш_роут')->with('success', 'урааа');
```

В блейде

```
@if (session('success'))
    {{ session('success') }}
@endif
```

**Для сообщения об ошибке:**

В контроллере

```
return redirect()->route('ваш_роут')->withError('нееееет');
```

Тут ситуативно. Например вместо редиректа и роута можно указать back(), или вообще добавить отправленные пользователем поля формы через withInputs().

В блейде

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```